# Hidden Storage Usage on Root Partition - Can’t Locate Files

Tags: debian, storage

I'm encountering a problem with the `df` command on my Debian 11.8 system. According to df, almost 90% of the space on my `/` (root) partition is being used. However, the root partition (formatted as ext4) does not appear to be actually that utilized. All important directories (`/var`, `/boot`, `/tmp`, `/home`, etc.) have their own partitions. I have checked all directories and files stored on /, but I could only account for a few GBs, which shouldn't make up the reported 90% usage.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Searched for hidden files and directories using `du -sch .[!.]* * | sort -h`
- Checked all files and directories with `ls -lah` and `du -hs`
- Cleaned the apt cache using `apt-get clean`
- Looked for open/used but deleted files via `lsof +L1` and `lsof | grep deleted`
- Used ncdu to search for files and directories
- Rebooted the system
- Checked for old and unused installed kernels
- Checked mounts and `/etc/fstab` for "shadow-mounts"

Do you have any tips for why I might be seeing high usage without being able to identify the corresponding files?

Comment: I would suggest of trying `cd /; du -sh -d 1`

Comment: It might have been helpful if you had included the output of at least the DF and DU commands.